# how to split "/" in mysql MarinDB then select json format value?

Tags: javascript, php, json, vue.js

how to split "/" in mysql MarinDB then select json format value?

in my database values is

```
/var/www/html/files/security/changeManage/2021_05_04_/
/var/www/html/files/security/changeManage/2021_05_05_/
/var/www/html/files/security/changeManage/2021_05_06_/
/var/www/html/files/security/kpi1/avu_KPI/109_1/
/var/www/html/files/security/kpi2/avu_KPI/109_2/
/var/www/html/files/security/kpi3/avu_KPI/109_3/
/var/www/html/files/security/kpi4/avu_KPI/110_1/
/var/www/html/files/security/kpi5/avu_KPI/110_3/
/var/www/html/files/security/securityMeeting/securityWorkMetting/avuMeeting/
```

Because I'd have many different folders, how could do split, and make to json format? I hope I can do like this json format.

```
export const fileItems = [{
  'name': 'Documents',
  'isDirectory': true,
  'items': [{
    'name': 'Projects',
    'isDirectory': true,
    'items': [{
      'name': 'About.rtf',
      'isDirectory': false,
      'size': 1024
    }, {
      'name': 'Passwords.rtf',
      'isDirectory': false,
      'size': 2048
    }]
  }, {
    'name': 'About.xml',
    'isDirectory': false,
    'size': 1024
  }, {
    'name': 'Managers.rtf',
    'isDirectory': false,
    'size': 2048
  }, {
    'name': 'ToDo.txt',
    'isDirectory': false,
    'size': 3072
  }],
}, {
  'name': 'Images',
  'isDirectory': true,
  'items': [{
    'name': 'logo.png',
    'isDirectory': false,
    'size': 20480
  }, {
    'name': 'banner.gif',
    'isDirectory': false,
    'size': 10240
  }]
}, {
  'name': 'System',
  'isDirectory': true,
  'items': [{
    'name': 'Employees.txt',
    'isDirectory': false,
    'size': 3072
  }, {
    'name': 'PasswordList.txt',
    'isDirectory': false,
    'size': 5120
  }]
}, {
  'name': 'Description.rtf',
  'isDirectory': false,
  'size': 1024
}, {
  'name': 'Description.txt',
  'isDirectory': false,
  'size': 2048
}];
```

So first, how could I do? How to determine if there are different levels of folders?

this is my sql code

```
select 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`upld_FilePath`,'/',6),'/',-1) AS part1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`upld_FilePath`,'/',7),'/',-1) AS part2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`upld_FilePath`,'/',8),'/',-1) AS part3,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`upld_FilePath`,'/',9),'/',-1) AS part4
upld_FileName as name
from  UploadFile
```

and this is my get json type

```
[
    {
        "UploadFile": [
            {
                "name": "SecurityManage",
                "part1": "Officer",
                "part2": "CheckReport",
                "part3": "SelfReport",
                "part4": "100_02_01"
            },
            {
                "name": "SecurityManage",
                "part1": "Officer",
                "part2": "SecurityMetting",
                "part3": "SecurityWorkingMetting",
                "part4": "101_02"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let arr = xhr.data.result[0].smsL_UploadFile;
var tree = {};
arr.forEach((item) => {
  //debugger;
  let tokens = item.path.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, "").split("/");
  let current = tree;
  for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    if (!current[tokens[i]]) {
      current[tokens[i]] = {};
    }
    current = current[tokens[i]];
  }
});
//debugger;
const parseNode = function (node) {
  //debugger;
  return Object.keys(node).map((key) => {
    //debugger;
    if (Object.keys(node[key]).length === 0) {
      return {
        isDirectory: false,
        name: key,
      };
    }
    return {
      isDirectory: true,
      name: key,
      items: parseNode(node[key]),
    };
  });
};
```